# How was a single arrow able to do this in What If...? S1E3?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, marvel-what-if-2021, hawkeye

In *What If...?* season 1 episode 3, "What If... Earth Lost its Mightiest Heroes?", Clint Barton is ready to shoot Thor at Mjolnir's landing site when Hank Pym forces him to shoot. However, this instantly kills Thor, who is a literal *god*. I couldn't quite see where the arrow went through, but even if it hit something vital, Thor probably would have been able to handle it, aside from the fact that his reflexes likely would have been able to catch it. How does a single arrow kill an Asgardian god? Is it possible that without his powers and Mjolnir he was weakened?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When Odin cast Thor to Earth in the first *Thor* movie, he stripped him not only of his hammer and armour, but his power as well.

> ODIN: Thor Odinson, you have betrayed the express command of your king. Through your arrogance and stupidity, you've opened these peaceful realms and innocent lives to the horror and desolation of war! You are unworthy of these realms! You're unworthy of your title! You're unworthy of the loved ones you have betrayed. **I now take from you your power!** In the name of my father and his father before, I, Odin Allfather, cast you out!
>
> <sub>*Thor* (2011)</sub>

Thor later acknowledges his weakness -- relative to Sif, Volstagg, Fandral and Hogun -- when he tells them that he's "just a man", and that he'd only be a liability if he tried to help them fight the Destroyer. The other Asgardians were all stronger than he was at this point in the film, so they took on the Destroyer without him.

> THOR: Jane, you have to leave.
>
> JANE FOSTER: What are you gonna do?
>
> THOR: I'm staying here.
>
> VOLSTAGG: Thor's going to fight with us!
>
> THOR: **My friends, I'm just a man. I'll only be in the way, or worse, get one of you killed.** But I can help get these people to safety.
>
> <sub>*Thor* (2011)</sub>

As Silly but True notes in [his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/256948/122024), Thor isn't truly immortal anyway, but in the scene where he was shot by Barton's arrow, he wasn't even superhuman. It's unclear what, if any, effect that arrow would've had on him if he'd been fully-powered at the time.

Comment: Definitely a good answer, but @Silly but True had it first. Good on the quote though!

Comment: Our answers differ significantly, so the consideration shouldn't be which was posted first, but which makes the better and more verifiably accurate argument. My answer shows that Thor had no powers when he was hit by the arrow, which explains why it killed him. Silly but True's answer ignores this, and implies that Thor would've been killed anyway, which isn't necessarily true. Sure, Thor isn't immortal even with his powers, but he's far more resilient than a normal human, so it's far from clear that the arrow would've inflicted a fatal wound, had he been fully-powered when it struck him.

Comment: I just think the other one makes more sense. You have valid points, and honestly, both answers are great. I could just as easily choose yours and I'll have to think on it

Comment: I've pointed out a clear weakness in Silly but True's answer: it implies that Barton's arrow would've killed Thor even if he still had his superhuman attributes, but offers no evidence to support that conclusion.

Comment: I got that. And honestly your answer seems better, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 8):

Asgardians are not immortal.

Odin died.

As confirmed in *Loki*, 9,719 Asgardians died during the fall of Asgard as seen in *Thor: Ragnarok*, which the TVA classified as a Class 7 apocalypse.

Of those Asgardians remaining, Thanos killed about another 3/4 more — slaughtering half on the ship by hand, and then killing another half of that remaining half with his snap.

Thor, being an Asgardian, can still be killed by weapons. In the comics, Thor has been killed multiple times.

Comment: "multiple times", hopefully, does not involve necromancing. although that would be interesting

Comment: That’s actually a sort of: Thor was killed in Marvel Zombies, and then zombified.

Comment: Ha, you got me there.

Comment: As a counter-argument to this answer, in the comics, Thor or mortals given his powers have repeatedly been shown to be bulletproof, in issues such as _Thor Vol. 1 #480_ and _Thor Vol. 4 #6_. Thor also had an axe break off on his chest in _Thor Vol. 2 #82_. As such, it's not at all clear that the fully-powered Thor from the comics would be killed by a single arrow to the chest from Hawkeye.

Comment: That's true. Good argument

Comment: @SillybutTrue sorry but I'm going to accept the other answer. Thank you for answering however and I upvoted it, your work is appreciated.

Comment: Np. It’s more reasoned. 

Comment: "The humans think us immortal. Should we test that?"

Comment: @LogicDictates True. But bullets and arrows aren’t the same penetration mechanism; bullets are blunt force trauma: bullets flatten and energy is transferred much differently while arrows are generally piercing weapons. “Bulletproof vests” for example won’t protect against many arrows or crossbows — although I’m not suggesting Asgardian skin is like some sort of Kevlar weave.

Comment: @SillybutTrue You're right that those have different methods of penetration, but given that an axe was also unable to cut him it's safe to assume that arrows wouldn't either unless it's a very narrow combination of sharpness and velocity (with the bullet being too blunt and the axe being too slow), but that seems pretty unlikely

Comment: @Kevin Arrows conceivably have lots of mass + very small cross-section (piercing).  Bullets have less mass (albeit higher speed) and an axe has more mass but at the cost of higher cross-section.  Let's also keep in mind this is a Hawkeye arrow and therefore likely to be more deadly than a typical arrow.

It's also worth noting someone can be shot with two identical bullets and have drastically different outcomes depending on the specifics of each hit - e.g. one that bounces off ribs, vs one that hits a major artery or organ.